# Concatenating 219 single entry CSV files into one Matlab Variable

Tags: matlab, csv, for-loop

--A bit of an update, managed to find a way around this on python. --

I am attempting to concatenate 219 single entry CSV files from a previous export into one Matlab variable file (MAT, CSV - I know how to interchange file formats well enough I'll take what I get on this for the process).  The files were written in '10' 'precision' in 'dlmwrite' in a 'for' loop writing one value per file.  I need to be able to combine the files, in an indexed order (from 1:73 per 1:3 variable blocks) to produce 3 master variables for statistics/plotting (e.g., usefulness).

Input try 1

```
for    k = 1:73
FileName0 = sprintf('D:/xxxx/yyy%dy.csv',k);
xx = dlmread(FileName0);
end
```

Input try 2

```
for    k = 1:73
FileName0 = sprintf('D:/xxxx/yyy%dy.csv',k);
xx = dlmread(FileName0);
if (rem(k,1)==0)
xx2 = [xx2,x];
end
```

Prospective Output 1 (for each variable - fyi, just need to know how to run once, have code setup otherwise).

```
size(xx(k,1)) = [73 1] %just informative about the desired size
dlmwrite('D:/xxxx/yyy.csv',xx,'precision',10)
```

Prospective Output 2 (for each variable - fyi, just need to know how to run once, have code setup otherwise).

```
size(xx2(k,1)) = [73 1] %just informative about the desired size
dlmwrite('D:/xxxx/yyy.csv',xx2,'precision',10)
```

Comment: Could you post examples of the desired input and output, please

Comment: Can you let your OS do it for you with `! cat yyy{1..73}.csv > batch1.csv` - ooops, no, you are on Windows :-(

Comment: Oh, I'll just go home and do it on my Linux machine, hmm...

Comment: Or make a live Knoppix distro and boot that temporarily :-)